How can something be both a primitive notion and be axiomatically defined like it is here?
This resource states that

In mathematics, the notion of a set is a primitive
notion. That is, we admit, as a starting point, the existence of certain objects
(which we call sets), which we won’t define, but which we assume satisfy some
basic properties, which we express as axioms.

I am confused why we can both have a a set be a primitive notion, and demand certain properties of it as axioms. From Wikipedia here, a primitive notion in mathematics and formal systems is defined to be "a concept which is not defined in terms of previously defined concepts". However, by  stipulating something of a set axiomatically, are we not using previously defined concepts to circumscribe what a set is, thereby rendering a set defined in terms of previously defined concepts, contradicting the fact that it is a primitive notion?

"I thought a  primitive notion was a preconceived mental construct which we had prior to using the term." No, no, no, no, no. That is not what "primitive" means in the context of formal axiomatic theory. Perhaps try to read a basic introduction instead of random resources from the web whose prerequisites are unclear?

@ArturoMagidin I edited my question to be in terms of a definition of a primitive notion given by Wikipedia in the context of formal mathematics

In formal axiomatic theory, a primitive notion is an undefined notion, a primitive function is an undefined function, a primitive operation is an undefined operation. The axioms establish properties that these undefined notions must satisfy. Theorems can only use the properties established by the axioms. Your confusion is, quite simply, an ignorance of what a formal axiomatic theory is, so that is what you need to learn. Hence, get thee to a library and get an introduction to the subject.

The problem here is not confusion, it is just plain ignorance. You are trying to run before you know enough to crawl. So learn to crawl first.

@ArturoMagidin out of curiosity, are there any books specifically you would recommend regarding formal axiomatic theory?

Not at all. To use an analogy, suppose we treated "dogs" as a primitive notion, one that we require to satisfy the property "it barks". But it doesn't go the other way — you cannot use the property of barking to define dogs, for there are other things satisfying the same property that are not dogs (seals, for instance)

We do not "define" it in the rigorous sense of the term: there is no axiom saying $\forall x [\text { Set}(x) \leftrightarrow \text {blah }]$, but we have axioms stating properties of sets. Thus, the axioms of the tehory "characterize" what sets are describing their behaviour: this means that - from the point of view of set theory - the only way to answer to the question "What a set is?" is to assert "A set is whatever satisfies the axioms of set theory".

"I am confused why we can both have a a set be a primitive notion, and
demand certain properties of it as axioms."
Because how else would you talk about a primitive notion? If I add a symbol, let's say $\mathbf{?}$ into the language without telling you anything, how would  you know what it does? Therefore I must give a minimal set of statements describing those notions that are accepted to be true i.e. axioms.
